# Retrieving data from firestore and storing it in a list (flutter)

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to retrieve data from firebase firestore so I can use it to display search reults by name inside my app. I've tried everything but still didn't work for me, any help?

Here are [My search class](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yI2nZ.png) And [My Firestore Database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bEDqL.png).

Answer (score 0):

Use: `searchSnapshot!.docs[index].data()["userName"]` and `searchSnapshot!.docs[index].data()["userEmal"]`

`data` isn't a variable; it is a method so the brackets are required.

Comment: Thanks for answering, I tried that already and it returns: _CastError (Null check operator used on a null value).. @Josteve

Comment: Where did you initialise `searchSnapshot`?

Comment: Here it is: QuerySnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>? searchSnapshot;

Comment: Not the declaration, where did you set a value to it?

Comment: I thought that I can do null checks in searchTile() by adding '?' to searchSnapshot! because i've defined it as late at the beginning!